# Tag rename request: [roller-coaster-xxx] -> [rollercoaster-xxx]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request

The official name is RollerCoaster Tycoon X. See [here](https://www.rollercoastertycoon.com/), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RollerCoaster_Tycoon_%28series%29), [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/285310/), [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rollercoaster-tycoon-4-mobile/id797639732?mt=8). You name it. There is no space between Roller and Coaster.

Answer (score 3):

I've created tags with the correct spelling and merged them with the old tags as synonyms, so that they will be correct from now on, along with being corrected on any existing questions, for all versions of Rollercoaster Tycoon.

Answer (score 0):

Did a quick look up of the the tag [roller-coaster-tycoon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roller-coaster-tycoon) and got the following feedback:

[image: 'roller-coaster' tags]

It appears there have been a few questions tagged using 'roller-coaster' as opposed to 'rollercoaster'. While "roller-coaster" still comes up as the suggested tag if you type "rollercoaster" into the tag field, I would suggest "rollercoaster-tycoon" as the main tag, with "roller-coaster-tycoon" as a synonym.

What ever decision should be applied to all 4 tags, to keep uniformity.